# Can someone explain what this Numpy array property is called?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting

The code that I have in place goes something as follows:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.array([
        [1, 2],
        [3]
])

x = np.array([
        [4, 5]
])
print(np.multiply(x,z))
```

The output of this program creates a list of lists. This is different than the regular broadcasting rules that apply on arrays with equal dimensions. Is there a name for this property? Also why does it explicitly mention the word list in the output?

```
[[list([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]) list([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])]]
[Finished in 0.244s]
```

Comment: You could just check the doc [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html)

Comment: Look at the `z.dtype`.

Comment: Because `z` is a object dtype array, the multiple effectively becomes a list comprehension, involving the elements of `x` and `z`.  `[i*j for i,j in zip(x,z)]`

Comment: Your variable `z` is an array having `lists` in it. Check the datatype of `z`.

Answer (score 3):

This is just normal cell-by-cell multiplication. Because your `z` array is not a true matrix (it does not have a square shape), Numpy interprets it as a row of two objects:

```
>>> z
array([[1, 2], [3]], dtype=object)
>>> z.shape
(2,)
```

From here here you multiply normally - the first object is multiplied by 4, the second by 5:

```
>>> [1, 2]*4
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
>>> [3]*5
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

just normal Python list multiplication - this is the result you get. Indeed, your result is not a "list of lists". It's an array of shape `(1, 2)` of `dtype=object`, so a row of two objects (which happen to be lists):

```
>>> np.multiply(x,z)
array([[[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]], dtype=object)
>>> np.multiply(x,z).shape
(1, 2)
```